# Problems with libcurl and JSON for Modern C++

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

I'm trying to teach myself C++ by writing a simple program that sends a cURL request to a JSON API, parses the data and then stores it either in a text document or database for a web application to access. I have done this task in PHP and figured C++ wouldn't be much harder but I can't even get cURL to return a string and display it.

I get this to compile with no errors, but the response `"JSON data: "` doesn't display anything where the JSON data should be.

Where did I go wrong? `URL-to-API` is the actual URL, so I believe I'm using a wrong `setopt` function, or not setting one. In PHP, `"CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER"` made it return as a string, but I get an error with it:

> error: ‘CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER’ was not declared in this scope
>   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

I'm using g++ compiler on Ubuntu and added `-lcurl` to the command line argument.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
//#include "json.hpp"

using namespace std;
//using json = nlohmann::json;

size_t WriteCallback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

string getJSON(string URL) {

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirect
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return as string
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);     

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        return readBuffer;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {

    string data = getJSON("URL-to-api");

    cout << "JSON Data: \n" << data;

    return 0;
}
```

When I uncomment the JSON for Modern C++ include and namespace line I get this error:

> error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Along with a bunch of errors for functions in that library. I just downloaded the most recent version of g++ before embarking on this project, so what do I need to do?

I'm using g++ 5.4.0 on Ubuntu.

UPDATE:

So I added a check under `res = curl_easy_perform(curl)` and it doesn't return the error message, and `res` gets displayed as `6`. This seems to be much more difficult than it should be:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
//#include "json.hpp"

using namespace std;
//using json = nlohmann::json;

size_t WriteCallback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

string getJSON(string URL) {

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirect
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);     

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        cout << res << endl;
        if (!res) {
            cout << "cURL didn't work\n";
        }

    /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl = NULL;
        return readBuffer;
    }
}

int main() {

    string data = getData("");

    cout << "JSON Data: \n" << data;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output when I run the program:

```
6
JSON Data:
```

Answer (score 1):

> In PHP "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER" made it return as a string but I get an error:
>
> error: ‘CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER’ was not declared in this scope
>  
>   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

There is no `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option documented for [`curl_easy_setopt()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html).  I think that is an option specify to PHP's [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) function, which doesn't exist in CURL itself. `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is the correct way to go in this situation.

> When I uncomment the JSON for Modern C++ include and namespace line I get:
>
> error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

The error is self-explanatory.  Your JSON library requires C++11 but you are not compiling with C++11 enabled.  Some modern compilers still default to an older C++ version (*usually* C++98) and require you to explicitly enable C++11 (or later) when invoking the compiler on the command line, or in your project makefile configuration.

In the case of g++, the current version (8.2) defaults to (the GNU dialect of) C17 for C and C++14 for C++, if not specified otherwise via the `-std` parameter.  Your version (5.4) defaults to (the GNU dialect of) C11 and C++98, respectively.

**UPDATE**: there are other mistakes in your code:

1. You are passing a `std::string` object to `curl_easy_setopt()` where a `char*` pointer is expected for `CURLOPT_URL`.  You need to change this:

   ```
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
   ```

   To this instead:

   ```
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
   ```
2. You are not testing the return value of `curl_easy_perform()` correctly.  Per the documentation, [`curl_easy_perform()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) returns 0 (`CURLE_OK`) on success, and non-zero on error, so you need to change this:

   ```
   if (!res)
   ```

   To this instead:

   ```
   if (res != CURLE_OK)
   ```
3. > So I added a check under `res = curl_easy_perform(curl)` ..., and `res` gets displayed as `6`.

   That is [`CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLECOULDNTRESOLVEHOST), which makes sense as your updated example is passing a blank `URL` to `getJSON()`:

   ```
   string data = getJSON(""); // should be "URL-to-api" instead!
   ```

Comment: So there is no way to set it by default that every time I use the compiler I want to use C++11? I read something in a Google search about using a makefile for every application. Is this the only way?

Comment: @BudgetBaller You are using an old version of g++, so you will have to explicitly specify the `-std=c++11` parameter every time, whether manually or via makefile, it doesn't matter.  Otherwise, upgrade your compiler to one that has C++11 enabled by default.

Comment: So after res = curl_easy_perform(curl); I added the lines:
  cout << res << endl;
  if (!res) {
   cout << "cURL didn't work\n";
  } And I get a message of "6
Tickers JSON: " on my console. Something isnt right about the cURL request. I use the same exact URL as my parameter in this as I do in PHP and my PHP script works perfect, I'm not seeing why its not working. Is readBuffer not reserving enough memory to hold the JSON string that gets returned or something?

Comment: @BudgetBaller Your handling of `readBuffer` is fine (though `getJSON()` is missing a `return` statement if `curl_easy_init()` fails). If you read the documentation more carefully, [`curl_easy_perform()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) returns 0 (`CURLE_OK`) on success and non-zero on error. Your code is expecting 0 on error, so you need to change `if (!res)` to `if (res)`. I would be more explicit and use `if (res != CURLE_OK)` instead. FYI, return value 6 is [`CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLECOULDNTRESOLVEHOST)

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried to upvote but since I have a new account it wont let me. I have it working fine now. Now I'm on to the JSON parsing aspect.